# How to use a patch in java

Tags: java, jcifs

I'm a rookie as to java.
I'm using an open source library named JCIFS.In its ZIP package,it has patches.And I want to use some functiones that only the patch has.But I don't know how.There are lots of irrelevant messages while I use google.Thus I ask here.
Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In ZIP package you probably have sources (maybe in src directory). I mean lots of *.java files and some with other extension. You have to apply patch on this files. At the beginning of patch it is specified which file you need. And then compile it all using `javac` and maybe package into jar.
If you don't have sources you have to get source for given class.
Then you have to apply patch on this file and compile it using `javac`. Then you will get .class file. You have to replace this file in .jar or .zip archive used with your system.

On Unix, you have the standard `patch` program to do that, but that ofcourse isn't normally present on Windows. If you want the `patch` command (and lots of other Unix utilities) on Windows, you could download and install [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/).

But looking at the patch file, it's very small and you could easily do the change by hand. Look at the patch file: The lines with a `-` in the left column must be removed. The lines with a `+` must be added.